# +initialise, is it possible to reset a class so the +initialize method gets called again

Tags: ios, objective-c

I understand that `+initialize` will be sent to each class the first time it is referenced (by message), including dynamically created classes.

But in the case of writing xcode unit tests, it does not reset everything back to zero, and part of my tests concentrate on multiple types of initialisation for classes.

Anyone know of anything secret I can send to a class to make the runtime "forget"?

I would rather not create and run complete separate test units individually if possible.

Comment: You need to use dependency injection to decouple your dependencies to avoid global variables.

Comment: To add to @BryanChen comment, checkout Swinject, it's been doing wonders for us in our shop for swift. A coworker made HGDependencyInjection, for OBJ-C

Comment: @Paulw11 totally edited my comment before I saw yours :)

Comment: @BryanChen thanks for the comment,  but I may be being a bit thick here but I'm not sure how dependency injection holds the answer to my issue.  My class needs to inspect its origins and store them away in a static variable somewhere,  as a one time affair.  It's not reliant on anything but itself.  Unless I've missed something in what you are saying?

Comment: I mean don't use global variable. (static variable is kind of global variable). Otherwise if you don't want to refactor everything, use global variable and add a method `[MyClass setSomething:]` which you can use to setup and teardown the global variable.

Comment: Right,  I see what you are saying.  But that isn't going to work for me (but it may have to),  as there is nothing I can set from outside that isn't the class Itself anyway.  So in this instance I would have to constantly test for a post initialised condition and if not,  setup my value again.  But this is so mind bogglingly slow that I've gone looking for this specific resolve.

Comment: I know this is holy war territory, but not everything can be unit tested.  If unit testing is an absolute requirement, you need a new design and/or implementation.

Comment: @Avi you are not wrong, it's a hugely contentious subject.  In my case, we are open sourcing our ORM and this has involved re-writes of large amounts of pretty core methods and huge amounts of refactoring.  We used to have a huge method that acted like a test script to check output, but in this case we are trying to cover every type of object, relationship, query, join etc... to ensure complete compatibility with the original.  So it's not essential, but we're testing only the API to ensure inputs and outputs are the same.   But we will not be changing code just to make it work in a test.